# with VSCODE for mac is their a keyboard binding to open the current highlight file in the side bar?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

command-O pulls up a system finder browser - looking for the binding to open the currently selected file in the side bar for editing... or a way to customize a binding to do the same action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay easy - "control enter" will "open to the side" for editing. simple enough